# getChildCount() returning 0 in OnActivityCreated - GridView / fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-gridview

I have a simple GridView / Fragement

public class member_list_image_fragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

```
//Current member list (array of member details from backend)
public static final String KEY_MEMBER_LIST = "member_list";

//Application's context
Context activity_context;

private ArrayAdapter<String> gridAdapter;
// gridView gridAdapter;

private GridView gridView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //get the activity context so it can be passed to the adapter
    activity_context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    return;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //define the view (home_screen_member_list_photo) that needs to be displayed when this fragment is called
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_screen_member_list_photo, container, false);


    GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.member_list_image_fragment_gridview);

    grid.setAdapter(new member_list_image_grid_adapter(activity_context));            

    this.gridView = grid;

    return view;
}




@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    GridView memberGridView = this.gridView;
    GridView mygridview  = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.member_list_image_fragment_gridview);
    GridView myactgridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.member_list_image_fragment_gridview);

    Log.w("1", String.valueOf(memberGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition()));
    Log.w("2", String.valueOf(memberGridView.getLastVisiblePosition()));
    Log.w("child",String.valueOf(memberGridView.getChildCount()));
    Log.w("child - mygrid",String.valueOf(mygridview.getChildCount()));
    Log.w("child - myactgrid", String.valueOf(myactgridview.getChildCount()));



    for(int visiblePosition = memberGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); visiblePosition <= memberGridView.getLastVisiblePosition(); visiblePosition++) {

        View member_row_view = memberGridView.getChildAt(visiblePosition);

        // Reset the ImageView           

        Log.w("image", "reset done");
    }

    return;
}
```

}

I am trying to get loop through all the items in the GridView and change the image icon(there is a reason why I would like to do this). But irrespective of how I try to get the GridView  and the associated getChildCount in onActivityCreated, they are return 0.

I have tried the following in onActivityCreated-

```
Log.w("child",String.valueOf(memberGridView.getChildCount()));
Log.w("child - mygrid",String.valueOf(mygridview.getChildCount()));
Log.w("child - myactgrid",String.valueOf(myactgridview.getChildCount()));
```

They all return 0. On the emulator, I am able to see the screen fully populated with the GridView with all the elements displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your grid won't have children as long as the grid is not displayed to the user. getChildCount will return the amount of visible children.